# How i can check if a value matches while multiprocessing is running

Tags: python, multiprocessing

What i want to do is check the Value "checker" periodically, but dont get the same value like def scraper, even i using global. i need this to make a contingency and if checker dont match the code restar the process.

```
from logging import WARN
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import multiprocessing

checker = 0

def warn():
  #DO STUFF 


def changing():
  global checker
  while True:
    #STUFFS
    time.sleep(1)
    checker += 1
    print('Value:', checker)


def proc_start():
  p_to_start = Process(target=changing)
  p_to_start.start()
  return p_to_start


def proc_stop(p_to_stop):
  p_to_stop.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  p = proc_start()
  while True:
   time.sleep(20)
   if checker > 10:
     checker = 0
   else:   
    warn()
    print('-----------------------RESTARTING-----------------------------------')
    proc_stop(p)
    p = proc_start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your sub-process and your main process see different versions of variable `checker` each existing in its own address space unique to the process that is running.

To get this to work `checker` needs to be created as in shared memory. In the code below a `multiprocessing.Value` instance is created with a lock under which modifications to the common `checker` value will be made so that each process sees consistent values. I also recommend that you familiarize yourself with the [PEP8 Style Guide for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You will not want to go through life using a single space for indenting new blocks of code.

```py
from logging import WARN
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import multiprocessing

def warn():
    #DO STUFF
    ...

def changing(checker):
    while True:
        #STUFFS
        time.sleep(1)
        with checker.get_lock():
            checker.value += 1
            print('Value:', checker.value)

def proc_start(checker):
    p_to_start = Process(target=changing, args=(checker,))
    p_to_start.start()
    return p_to_start

def proc_stop(p_to_stop):
    p_to_stop.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create shared unsigned long:
    checker = multiprocessing.Value('L', 0, lock=True)
    p = proc_start(checker)
    while True:
        time.sleep(20)
        with checker.get_lock():
            if checker.value > 10:
                checker.value = 0
            else:
                warn()
                print('-----------------------RESTARTING-----------------------------------')
                proc_stop(p)
                # Should checker be reset back to 0?
                #checker.value = 0
                p = proc_start(checker)
```

Prints:

```
Value: 1
Value: 2
Value: 3
Value: 4
Value: 5
Value: 6
Value: 7
Value: 8
Value: 9
Value: 10
Value: 11
Value: 12
Value: 13
Value: 14
Value: 15
Value: 16
Value: 17
Value: 18
Value: 19
Value: 1
Value: 2
Value: 3
Value: 4
Value: 5
Value: 6
Value: 7
Value: 8
Value: 9
etc.
```